# Kubernetes: How to manage lots of services ? Is grouping multiple applications in one service a bad idea?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

First of all, I'd like to say that I'm new to Kubernetes, so forgive me if what I want to do is a bad idea :)

Here's my context :
I've got a very large application which is composed of lots of micro-services according to their domains :

```
Domain 1
    domain1-microservice1-app expose port 8080
    domain1-microservice2-app expose port 8081
    domain1-microservice3-app expose port 8082

Domain 2
    domain2-microservice1-app expose port 9080
    domain2-microservice2-app expose port 9081
    domain2-microservice3-app expose port 9082

Domain 3
    domain3-microservice1-app expose port 9180
    domain3-microservice2-app expose port 9181
    domain3-microservice3-app expose port 9182
```

... and so on.

So, in my example, I have 9 applications. Each application is registered in Kubernetes using **kind:Deployment**

### Now I want to choose the best way to manage services.

#### First solution

Each deployment has its own service

=> It works, it seems to be the classical way of doing things in Kubernetes. But in reality, I have far more than 9 applications, so I have lots of services

#### Second solution

Create a service by domain. Each service contains all its related apps

=> I've tried it and it seems to work (as far as I could test in my local dev environment)

I'd like to know what do you think of my second solution, and what may be its caveat?

I also take all your advice on what could be the best Kubernetes structure.

Thanks a lot,

Julien

## Edit: add sample configuration files for approach 2

Deployment file for microservice1 of domain1 :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: domain1-app1
    labels: 
        domain: domain1  
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: domain1-app1
    replicas: 3
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: domain1-app1
                domain: domain1
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: XXX
                image: YYY
                ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
```

Service file for service related to domain 1 :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: domain1-service
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    selector:
        domain: domain1
    ports:
        - name: port8080
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
        - name: port8081
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8081
        targetPort: 8081
        - name: port8082
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8082
        targetPort: 8082
```

Answer (score 2):

It's subjective.

I would go with Approach 1 to keep the Service specifications simple. It will also be possible to have different Pods for different Services. With the Approach 2, the same set of Pods (based on the selector) should provide all the Services for a particular domain. It would be not possible to scale the Pods based on the Services.

Domain is more like metadata and not much with the functionality of the service. So, I would remove domain from service name and start using [labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) for it. This will allow to apply Selectors on Labels.

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks for your reply.

I've edited my question to provide my sample configurations files.
I already apply selectors on labels.

What do you mean by **It would be not possible to scale the Pods based on the Services** ? I thought that my pods were scaled based on their deployment configuration file ?

Regards,

Julien

Comment: The Service `domain1-service` will have all the pods with Labels `domain: domain1`. And all these pods should expose app on port 8080, 8081 and 8082. So, it should not be able to scale the apps behind these ports independently. It's a bit difficult to explain. Best way is to try scaling the apps independently in the Approach 2.

Comment: It's exactly what I thought : all pods in a service should expose the ports  managed by the service... And this is definitly not the case because each pod expose only on port.
But, according to my deployments file, I may have multple pods for the same microservice (replicas is set to 3 in my example) so the scaling will be done by that, I'll have 3 "identical" pods for microservice1 exposing port 8080, and other pods exposing other ports, no ?

Comment: As I mentioned the best way is to try it out. Have you?

Comment: Yes, I've already created my service, verified that my microservices (deployments contained in my service) were up and ensure that I can access them. So, it seems to work.
But I don't know if it is a good practice or not, and I don't know if the fact that my deployments/pods contained into my service are differents and expose differents ports can make the load balancing system crash. I mean, I'm not sure that the service will never intend to send request to one of his pods on a port that this pod doesn't expose

Comment: Try to scale all the 9 apps independently and you won't be able to do it.